# c# textbox font problem : same font looks completely different in app then in notepad

Tags: c#, fonts, textbox

I'm trying to display ascii-art in a textbox.
If I open a specific .nfo file in notepad with the font "Lucida Console", 9pt, regular, it looks like this :

http://i48.tinypic.com/24zvvnr.png

In my app I set the font of the textbox to "Lucida Console", 9 pt, regular, it looks like this :

http://i49.tinypic.com/2ihq8h0.png

What am I doing wrong ? 
(Or - what should I do to get it to look like in notepad ?)

Comment: I'm not a cracker, I just want to be able to show ascii-art in my app.
I've used an .nfo example because it was the easiest file to find that uses the extended character set.

Comment: It certainly seems to indicate that you're, at the very least, downloading software cracks. Perhaps it would be more advisable to use something less incriminating when posting here.

Comment: If you look at the nfo file, it still specifies adlib cards.
This is actually an nfo from a publicly accessible online antique nfo collection (people collecting nfo's for the sake of history), probably some 15 years old ;)

Comment: Hi, are you "embedding" this font in your application as a resource ? What GDI+ settings that might affect font-rendering have you set or not set ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem can be summed up like this:  **ASCII is not UTF-8, and UTF-8 is not ASCII**.

The `StreamReader(string)` constructor initializes the `StreamReader` to use `Encoding.UTF8`, which is a UTF-8 decoder that silently attempts to resolve invalid characters.  A very quick glance at [the Wikipedia page for .nfo files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo) reveals that most .nfo files are generally encoded in [Extended ASCII (aka Code Page 437)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437).  While the first 127 characters of ASCII map to the first 127 bit patterns of UTF-8, the encodings are **not** the same, and so you will get incorrect characters if you use one where the other is expected.

You probably want:

```
System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName, encoding);
```

Comment: You, Sir, are a hero !
Works like a charm, and now I understand the importance of using the right encoding :)
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

You're probably reading the file with the wrong encoding.

How are you opening the file?

Comment: using
    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(inFileName);

and then just ReadLine until the end.
Should I specify an encoding somewhere ?

Comment: Open the file in VS, click File, Advanced Save Options, and check what encoding it actually is.

Comment: Then I see what encoding this file is in, but is there a general encoding I can use for all ascii-art files..?

Comment: It depends on the files.  I have no idea where your files are coming from.